# Selecting all data from all columns in a MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, database, select, mysql-workbench

Say I have the following data in a database DB1:

Table1
id int (50)
attribute varchar(255)

Total Rows : 6550

Table2
id int (50)
attribute varchar(255)
attribute1 varchar(255)

Total Rows : 10550

and say more table possibly. I wish to get every single data element in all of the tables. Is there any SELECT statement or so that can do this? I tried using

```
select * from DB1.Table1 UNION ALL select * from DB1.Table2;
```

However, this gave me an error stating that the number of rows were different and hence could not be done. COuld someone please tell me if there was any way to do so?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to explicitly provide columns of each table. Like:

```
select id, attribute, '' AS attribute1 from DB1.Table1
UNION ALL 
select id, attribute, attribute1 from DB1.Table2;
```

Comment: But, what if I have a large database whose column names are too many to enumerate by hand? Can I do select columns from information_schema.tables and get the columns?

Comment: Unfortunately, you have to specify column names if you are using UNION for two tables with different structures.

Comment: If specify column names is that much issue then you can also create dummy columns in second table to create matching structure but it will be a crappy approach.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just do :
    Select * from db1.table1, db1.table2

Comment: That returns a join of both the tables, whereas I want them both in the same table or select statement, but without the join.

Answer (score 1):

A UNION would work, but don't use * and you will need to add an "extra" column to the SELECT on the first table (but the column doesn't have to actually exist in the table, it's just added so that the selections match). Something like this:

```
SELECT t1.id as 'id',
       t1.attribute as 'attribute',
       '' as 'attribute1'
FROM DB1.Table1 as t1

UNION ALL

SELECT t2.id as 'id',
       t2.attribute as 'attribute',
       t2.attribute1 as 'attribute1'
FROM DB1.Table2 as t2
```

Answer (score 0):

In a union, you must have the same number of columns on all the select statements. So saying "select * from table1 union select * from table2" won't work, you'd need to add dummy columns for any tables that have fewer columns than whichever one has the most.

And what would the results mean? You'd have a column that would, say, sometimes contain the customer zip code, sometimes the order total, and sometimes the employee number. What would you do with that?

If the point is just to dump out the entire contents of the db for a human being to look at, why not just do a separate select statement for each table?

Perhaps you need to step back and look at what you're trying to accomplish, rather than wrestle with how to get the db to do something that it is explicitly designed NOT to do because it doesn't make sense.